# How to set templateUrl and styleUrls

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I made a little application but it has all in app.component.ts . Now I'm trying break it into separate components and services. As the first step I have tried to split my code into separate components.
But I'm unable to set the templateUrl and styleUrls. My codes and error I got is shown below.
this is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { routes, navigatableComponents } from './app.routing';
import { SearchComponent } from './search-component/search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    NativeScriptHttpModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, SearchComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.ts file

```
import { SearchComponent } from './search-component/search.component';

export const routes = [
  { path: "", component: SearchComponent }
  ];

export const navigatableComponents = [
  SearchComponent
  ];
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
  <ActionBar title="Glossary" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
  <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`,
  styleUrls: ["app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

search.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `<Label text="search Here" class="small-spacing"></Label>`
})
export class SearchComponent {
  constructor(){
  }
}
```

now it is working correctly , but when i'm split my HTML and CSS into separate files like below. It gives error.

`templateUrl: "search.component/search.component.html",` and I tries this way also.

`templateUrl: "search.component.html",`

console shows this.

```
04-28 08:38:11.072  5202  5202 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
04-28 08:38:11.072  5202  5202 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1197)
04-28 08:38:11.072  5202  5202 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1061)
04-28 08:38:11.072  5202  5202 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1047)
04-28 08:38:11.072  5202  5202 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1028)
04-28 08:38:11.072  5202  5202 W System.err:    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1018)
```

GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/isuruAb/nativescript-dictionary)

Comment: try to `'./app.component.css'`

Comment: @Jerry06 in app.component.ts it is working fine. but problem occurs when I'm trying to give seperate files for search.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add one more moduleId property:

> If we decide on CommonJS formats AND we use a standard module loader,
>   then we can use the `module.id` variable which contains the absolute URL
>   of the component class [when the module file is actually loaded]: the
>   exact syntax is `moduleId: module.id`.
>
> This `moduleId` value is used by
>   the Angular reflection processes and the `metadata_resolver` component
>   to evaluate the fully-qualified component path before the component is
>   constructed.

**CommonJS**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: './reative/path'
})
export class SearchComponent {
  constructor(){
  }
}
```

and declare this object in root(root module for example)

```
declare var module: {
    id: string;
};
```

and more config from this post: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html

btw, you could using webpack for bundle, or [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for scaffolding app.

Comment: This worked but partially,I just added `moduleId: module.id`  i didn't declare that object.can you specify where i need to declare that ? app.module.ts ?
I have added github repo to my question as well. 
Now iOS application is working fine and android application is still like same

Comment: tsconfig.json
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5"
  }
}` and put your declare to app.module is fine.